How to configure output file size with pyspark ETL?
I have some ETL code, I read CSV data convert them to dataframes, and combine/merge the dataframes after certain transformations of the data via map utilizing PySpark RDD(Resilient Distributed Dataset). Finally, when I save the result as an output file, it saves the output into multiple files. Is there a way I can configure how many files it can output or specify the size for each file? So, I can have a certain number of lines/rows printed in each file?
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV files
df_one = pd.read_csv('one.csv')
df_two = pd.read_csv('two.csv')

# Merge on the truncated ID
df_combined = pd.merge(df_one , df_two , how='inner', left_on='truncated_id', right_on='id')

...

merged_rdd = merged.rdd.map(some_function)

merged_rdd.saveAsTextFile('/output.json')


Using df.iloc[n:m] lets you control the number of rows (pandas.Dataframe.iloc). Doing this in a cycle would help each of the CSV to have the same number of rows.
Although, to calculate each file's size you'd need to take into account the length of each cell's value representation as a string, plus possible double quote wrappings and escaped characters, not to forget about line endings and, of course, the header.

I don't think there is a direct way to control the number of rows per file but you can certainly control the number of output files by changing the partitions count before writing.
Use coalesce() to reduce the number of partitions eventually reducing the number of output files:
# Assuming you have number of partitions > 2
merged_rdd.coalesce(2).saveAsTextFile('/output.json')

Similarly, if you want to increase it - use repartition():
# Assuming you have number of partitions < 10
merged_rdd.coalesce(10).saveAsTextFile('/output.json')

Now for file sizes, you can maybe indirectly control them by adjusting the number of partitions based on your data size. For example, if you know your data has 1,000 rows and you want each file to have approximately 200 rows, you can repartition your RDD into 5 partitions.
